# Working Around the Windows-numpy astype(int) Bug in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, windows, numpy, cross-platform

I have a codebase I've been developing on a Mac (and running on Linux machines) based largely on pandas (and therefore numpy). Very commonly I type-cast with `astype(int)`.

Recently a Windows-based developer joined our team. In an effort to make the code base more platform-independent, we're trying to gracefully tackle [this tricky issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17640) whereby numpy uses a 32-bit type instead of the 64-bit type, which breaks longer integers.

On a Mac, we see:

```
ipdb> ids.astype(int)
id
1818726176      1818726176  
1881879486      1881879486  
2590366906      2590366906  
284399109       284399109   
299981685       299981685   
370708200       370708200   
387277023371    387277023371
387343898032    387343898032
406885699892    406885699892
5262665206      5262665206  
544687374       544687374   
6978317806      6978317806
```

Whereas on a Windows machine (in PowerShell), we see:

```
ipdb> ids.astype(int)
id
1818726176      1818726176
1881879486      1881879486
2590366906     -1704600390
284399109       284399109 
299981685       299981685 
370708200       370708200 
387277023371    729966731 
387343898032    796841392 
406885699892   -1136193228
5262665206      967697910 
544687374       544687374 
6978317806     -1611616786
```

Other than using a `sed` call to change every `astype(int)` to `astype(np.int64)` (which would also require an `import numpy as np` at the top of every module where currently that doesn't exist), is there a way to do this?

In particular, I was hoping to map int to numpy.int64 somehow in a pandas option or something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that this is a really good idea, but you can simply redefine `int` to whatever you want:

```
import numpy as np

x = 2384351503.0
print(np.array(x).astype(int))
#-2147483648

old_int = int
int = np.int64
print(np.array(x).astype(int))
#2384351503

int = old_int
print(np.array(x).astype(int))
#-2147483648
```

In the case you described I'd, however, **strongly prefer** to fix the source code instead of redefining standard data types. It's a one-time effort and any IDE can do it easyly.

`Numpy` is already implicitely imported by pandas, so it doesn't cost any additional time or resources. If you really want to avoid it (for whatever reason), you can use `pd.Int64Dtype.type` instead of `np.int64` (see [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b1e62a107f4773ba7766e84ef088dd50a4449d2d/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py#L531)).

Comment: Thanks; makes sense…I guess my hesitation is, “What other Windows-related changes will I have to make if I keep going down this path?”